# what does enable-inline-optimization do when compiling php

Tags: php, optimization, compilation

What exactly the --enable-inline-optimization option does when compiling PHP?

And why people would use it?

What are the pros and the cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inlining (also known as [inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion)) is a way to optimize a program by replacing function calls with the actual body of the function being called at compile-time.

It reduces some of the overhead associated with function calls and returns, and in some cases (I'm not sure if PHP is one of these) can allow the compile to further optimize an area of code after inlining such as by removing code that has no effect.

The main drawback to allowing a compiler to perform inline expansion is the increase in code size, which can be significant considering that the single function call is being replaced with all of the code from the function being called.

Enabling this configuration option will result in potentially faster php scripts that have a larger file size.

Comment: Does a benchmark exist that proves inline-expansion actually improves performance of php? I am curious if we are talking a couple percentage points or significantly higher?

Comment: @ck_ not really incredibly eloquent, but still: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/3#null